# Reading data.json with HttpClient on Stackblitz?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, stackblitz

[I have a tiny demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-httpclient-local-data?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) and it attempts to read `app/data.json` using the Angular HttpClient.

```
const post$:Observable<Post> = <Observable<Post>> http.get('./data.json');
```

However the `HttpClient` reponse says:

> Failure during parsing ...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stackblitz currently doesn't serve static files except the case when they are in `assets` folder.

So you have two options here:

1) Import json directly as module

```
import data from './data.json';

console.log(data) // => {title: "Simulating HTTP Requsts", content: "This is off the hook!!"}
```

For more details See other answers

2) Move that json in assets folder(***Note***: you have to reload stackblitz to 
make it working):

```
http.get('/assets/data.json')
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-httpclient-local-data-b6mcy4?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you can't get the JSON directly over HTTP, but you can import it instead

**data.json**

it returns resource of index.html instead of the data you expected

[image]

---

[online example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-httpclient-local-data-tzzzza?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import data from './data.json';

export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(http:HttpClient) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    const post$ = of(data);
    post$.subscribe(console.log);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think there are some [issues](https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/331) about reading local json in stackblitz it doesn't return plain json just the index.html instead. but another way is mocking a request from local json, you can try:

```
import data from './data.json'

ngOnInit(){
  this.getDatas().subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(data)
  })
}

getDatas():Observable<any>{
  return of(data).pipe(delay(1000));
}
```

forked [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-httpclient-local-data-kpdopm)