# Angular Http failure during parsing

Tags: json, angular, http

I am new to angular please help to identify the issue here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ntqzd6

Http failure during parsing for https://angular-ntqzd6.stackblitz.io/assets/data/employee.json"

Comment: Put a [mcve] *in the question*.

Comment: Fix - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049933/reading-data-json-with-httpclient-on-stackblitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've placed your `assets` directory inside your `app` directory. If you want to keep this structure, you'll have to update the `angular.json` to:

```
...
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/app/assets"
],
...
```

Additionally, you should notice that there is an **open** [issue](https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/577) in the StackBlitz Github repository regarding asset serving. You should definitely switch to a local IDE for development like [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/), if you aren't already using one.

Comment: Thanks. But it is not working if I put asset outside app.(https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zuw1fl) . I got a similar  sample which is working(https://stackblitz.com/edit/htpgeterror-7tc5v70) . But could not identify the exact issue

Comment: Did you try it in a local IDE? Stackblitz is having issues with assets: https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/577